# Require dependency of dependency

Tags: node.js, node-modules

[image]

I have the modules as shown above. I need to include not only `quickblox`, but the `quickblox.chat` plugin.

I'm using this code:

```
// Quickblox
var QB = require('quickblox');
var QBChat = require('quickblox/plugins/chat');
```

`quickblox` loads fine but `quickblox/plugins/chat` throws:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'quickblox/plugins/chat'
```

Here is the `package.json` included in the `quickblox/plugins/chat` directory:

```
 {
  "name": "quickblox.chat",
  "description": "Quickblox Javascript SDK / XMPP Chat plugin",
  "version": "0.8.6",
  "author": "Andrey Povelichenko <andrey.povelichenko@quickblox.com>",
  "homepage": "http://quickblox.com/developers/Web_XMPP_Chat_Sample"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call require with a folder path, it tries to load `index.js`, which doesn't exist.

```
var QBChat = require('quickblox/plugins/chat/quickblox.chat');
```